# CakePHP: Allowed memory size exhausted, increasing memory_limit is not helping

Tags: php, apache, cakephp, memory-leaks, cakephp-2.4

Specs = CakePHP 2.4.6, PHP 5.3.13, Windows 7 x64, Apache Server 2.4.9.

I keep getting this error:

```
Allowed memory size xxxx exhausted
```

I have tried everything I could find, increasing `memory_limit` or `max_execution_time` inisde php.ini file is not helping no matter how much I increase the limits. My Apache server has openssl enabled (some say it might be related), php_pdo_mysql is enabled too. I am using fastCGI for PHP and it's not helping to switch to php5_module!

The strange thing is that it was working on my localhost for a while and not working on the dev server, and recently it's not working on my localhost as well (I started getting execution time error instead sometimes)

Here is the action I am using:

```
public function index() {

    $this->Certificate->recursive = 0; 
    $certificates = $this->Certificate->find('all',         
        array(       
        'conditions' => array('course_id !=' => '1'),       
        'contain' => array(

                         'CertificateStatus.status',
                         'Course.title',
                         'Student.full_name',
                         'User.name'

                 )));
    $this->set(compact('certificates'));
}
```

Any ideas as to what could be the reason for this problem? how would I find memory leaks in CakePHP? What could be the solution to fix/optimize it?

** New Update:

After limiting the number of "fields" in the `find()`, and after increasing some Fcgid numbers inside httpd, now I can fetch the whole table, but it takes 5 minutes for the page to load completely, which is a failure performance wise!

Is this related to CakePHP caching? If yes, is there any way to optimize it for this number of records?? Everyone tells me that 26,000 text records is not a "huge" data set!

Comment: possible duplicate of [CakePHP error Allowed memory size exhausted](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6483162/cakephp-error-allowed-memory-size-exhausted)

Comment: I read the article referred in your link[ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6483162/cakephp-error-allowed-memory-size-exhausted] already, Nunser, and none of the suggestions there worked.

Comment: Then you should post the action in particular that's draining all the memory so we can help you optimize it. I don't believe that if you have implemented Containable behavior as the other question says, that you could be running out of memory on *every* action.

Comment: Ok, I will check that out again and I will get back with the results

Comment: Nunser, the code (using Containable) is provided, and again, its not helping. BTW number of records I am fetching is > 26000

Comment: What are you trying to do ? Dealing with 26000 records on a single HTTP request sounds as something that should be avoided. As you seems to pass them to the view, I guess you want to show them ? So why not using pagination ? And if your goal is not to show them but to do some treatment, a shell script would certainly be more appropriated.

Comment: nIcO, This is supposed to be an online database interface. I am not using cakephp pagination, instead I am using the JQuery Datatables plugin. There is a need to show these records to be able to search for, view, edit, and delete each one. The problem is, it was working find on my localhost (only) with 128M memory_limit size, and now its not working no matter how much I put this size to (including -1 )!

Comment: Let's compare with phpMyAdmin: you can search, view, edit and delete records. But it doesn't use queries that return all records at the same time. Even if you manage to make your page work the way you want, what will happen when you will have 500'000 records ? At some point it will break the memory again (Apache or even worse, the server memory). Using a jQuery plugin doesn't change anything: you should fetch the records as batches. Also think of how much memory browsers will consume with all records in the page, be they shown or not. I think you should really better change your design.

Comment: nIcO, and what exactly you are suggesting to change and how to implement the batches-fetching approach? I am aware of this "idea" but I haven't seen how to apply it in CakePhp, would you direct me to a reference pls? thanks

Comment: Does that mean CakePHP was never meant to build an online Interfaces for databases?? that would be a shame!

Comment: SQL's purpose is to search large datasets (using `WHERE` clauses and the like) to produce human-sized result sets. Your cakephp code shouldn't be trying to buffer 26K records in web server RAM.  Rather, you should be passing your search criteria from jQuery to php to the database, and rendering subsets of the dataset. It's true that 26K records is a medium size *table*. But it's an over-the-top too-large *result set*.

Answer (score 3):

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
```

overrides the default PHP memory limit.

Comment: I tried this one before, and then I get the error: `Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded` (I increased it from 30 to 60 seconds)

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '1024M');
```

Answer (score 1):

Indrajeet answer worked for me.

To improve his answer, simply go to `app/lib/Cake/I18N/I18N.php` and in the function `public function _construct()` add the line

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '1024M');
```

Comment: Why in I18N.php? Is it because I18N.php is memory hungry?

Answer (score 0):

```
    set_time_limit(0);

    ini_set('memory_limit','2048M');
```

i have used set_time_limit function to handle mysql expiration time and  ini_set function to handle size of data to be stored